# Call a String... function with String[]

Tags: java, string

How can I call a function which accepts unknown number of `String` inputs (e.g. `void func(String... strs)`) with a given `String` array (`String[]`)?

Comment: by simply calling it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Varargs arguments are in fact arrays. Given this method:

```
void func(String... strs);
```

Calling it is simple (the following are the same):

```
func("a", "b", "c");
func(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
```

The method implementation can then do things, such as:

```
void func(String... strs) {
  System.out.println("Array length:  " + strs.length);
  System.out.println("Array content: " + strs[0]);
}
```

Understand that varargs arguments are just syntactic sugar for call-site convenience.

Answer (score 3):

A String varargs, is a String array. You just simply call it and pass the String array.